# Passing 0 to the shared pointer with deleter as the first argument

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm readin Scott Meyrse C++ and now I'm at the section about deigning interfaces. The following code is supposed to be invalid:

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<Investment> // attempt to create a null
pInv(0, getRidOfInvestment);     // shared_ptr with a custom deleter;
                                 // this won’t compile
```

He gave the following explanation:

> The `tr1::shared_ptr` constructor insists on its first parameter being a
>   pointer, and 0 isn’t a pointer, it’s an int. Yes, it’s convertible to
>   a pointer, but that’s not good enough in this case; tr1::shared_ptr
>   insists on an actual pointer.

I tried similar example myself http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4199bdf68a1d6e19

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct B{
    explicit B(void *){ }
};

void del(int*){ }
int main()
{
    B b(0);
    std::shared_ptr<int*> ptr(0, del);
}
```

and it compiles and runs fine even in spite of passing `0` as the first argument.

What did he mean actually? Isn't that relevant already?

Comment: In the question you are talking about `std::tr1::shared_ptr` In the code snippet you are using `std::shared_ptr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is from `#include <tr1/memory>`; the other is from `#include <memory>`. There is a difference:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f76ea0ef17227d9d

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/memory>
#include <memory>

struct B{
    explicit B(void *){ }
};

void del(int*){ }
int main()
{
    B b(0);
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<int*> ptr(0, del);
    std::shared_ptr<int*> ptr2(0, del);
}
```

It gives the error for the `tr1` version but not the current standard version.

Comment: But how to do that constructor does not accept 0, but insist on the actual pointer? I [tried](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db520f7e80c22f86) `explicit` one but it didn;t work.

Comment: I don't think you understand what `explicit` actually does. It does not apply in these examples because you are not creating instances of `B` or `shared_ptr` implicitly.

Comment: In any case, in C++11 use of `NULL` for a null pointer is deprecated, it has been replaced with a new `nullptr` keyword instead, which has a distinct type of `std::nullptr_t`, which can be used in overload resolution. A literal `0` is implicitly convertible to `nullptr_t`, and `std::shared_ptr` has a constructor that accepts a `nullptr_t` as input.  I do not know if `std::tr1::shared_ptr` has a `nullptr_t` constructor, but I am guessing not, which could explain the error. It definitely does not have a constructor that accepts an `int` as input.

Comment: On the other hand, a `0` literal is also implicitly convertible to a pointer, so why `std::tr1::shared_ptr` will not accept `0` as input, I do not know. You will have to look at the actual constructor declarations between `std::tr1::shared_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` to see what is different, clearly there is a difference.